# WebStorm removing highlight around Angular code in html files

Tags: webstorm, syntax-highlighting

I've been searching through the settings in WebStorm and can't seem to find out how to get rid of the background color for Angular code in my html attributes. The rest of the color scheme seems fine to me but the background just makes everything feel washed out. Example below:

[image: green highlight]

Anyone know how to get rid of this?

Edit:
Same shot in default theme.

[image]

Comment: Please provide the same screenshot but using Default color schema.

Comment: Not seeing any kind of background in the default color scheme so I guess it's scheme specific. The one I've been using (first screenshot) is called Twilight.

Comment: I see some light green background. Check it -- that could be it: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General | Code | Injected language fragment`. Since I'm not AngularJs user ... I just cannot say if it meant to be like that (I'm talking about actual injection) or you have created such injection yourself (that's, of course, if it is an injection fragment there).

Comment: That did it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the screenshot taken with Default color schema .. please check the following:

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | Colors & Fonts | General`
3. `Code | Injected language fragment`